# Цикл for в python. Как сократить

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно заменить код

```
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('sprite/right_1.png'), pygame.image.load('sprite/right_2.png'),
            pygame.image.load('sprite/right_3.png'), pygame.image.load('sprite/right_4.png'),
            pygame.image.load('sprite/right_5.png'), pygame.image.load('sprite/right_6.png')]
```

на менее громоздкий. Например так:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    walkRight = my_list[pygame.image.load('sprite/right_[i].png')]
```

У меня не получается

Comment: Я не знаю питон, но, возможно, вам нужно просто сложить: "sprite/right_" + i + ".png".

Comment: @Miron К сожалению это так не работает. В квадратных скобках.

Comment: Попробуйте вывести 'sprite/right_[i].png' в консоль. Может, обнаружите ошибку

Comment: Ошибка то есть, что я не знаю как пишется команда

Comment: @Miron, у него ещё в условии цикла косяк - он проходит не по массиву, а по индексам от 0 до длины. А ещё тут надо результат в массив сложить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
walk_right = [pygame.image.load('sprite/right_%s.png' % (i+1))
              for i in range(6)]
```

Comment: `range(1,7)` же?

Comment: @Qwertiy, там внутри i+1

Comment: Да, я имел в виду, что его можно заменить.

Comment: Спасибо сработало